# How to overcome - pip install ansible on windows failing with filename or extension too long on windows

Tags: python, windows, pip

how to fix the pip install failures on windows with below error. Getting this error while trying to install ansible.

I suspect it is with issue with selected pip package for install. but the same is working fine with Linux based systems. Will there be any difference with OS for pip install

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 663, in unpack_http_url
    unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 605, in unpack_file
    untar_file(filename, location)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 553, in untar_file
    ensure_dir(path)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 206] The filename or extension is too long: 'c:\\users\\user123\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-isnb2t\\ansible\\test/integration/targets/copy/files/subdir/subdir1/circles/subdir1/circles/subdir1/circles/subdir1/circles/subdir1/circles/subdir1/circles/subdir1/circles/subdir1/circles/subdir1/circles/subdir1/'
```

Comment: symlink loop maybe

Comment: @wim: maybe, except that there aren't any symlinks in windows. The above path is exactly 256 chars long BTW.

Comment: why does there different slashes \\ and / ?

Comment: also note that first part has backslashes whereas second part (the part that loops) has slashes. Weird

Comment: what is the exact `pip install` command BTW? do you have the same issue with all packages? have you tried to upgrade `pip` ?

Comment: pip install ansible. It is failing for very couple of packages. Most of other package installations are fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it seems to be a known bug:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/31419

> In Ansible 2.4.0, the module copy use symbolic links in the tests suite: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/test/integration/targets/copy/files/subdir/subdir1

```
circles -> ../
subdir3 -> ../subdir2/subdir3
```

Windows 10, cannot create this directories tree because the path is too long. In fact the resolved path is:

```
test/integration/targets/copy/files/subdir/subdir1/circles/subdir1/circles/subdir1/circles/subdir1/circles/subdir1/circles/subdir1/circles/subdir1/circles/subdir1/circles/subdir2/subdir3/
```

bug report ends with:

> We do not support installing ansible directly on a windows machine. You will need a linux like operating system to install ansible on

## Workaround

A possible workaround is to download the wheel on pypi, it doesn't depend on Linux or whatever, probably pure python:

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ansible/2.5.0a
```

(the `pip install ansible` command downloads the "source" .tgz archive, performs tests, ... and the path issue is within the tests, so let's use a ready-to-use pre-built bundle)

Once downloaded, use `pip install path/to/the/wheel/file.whl`

Tested and installed successfully on my Windows 10 machine:

```
C:\Users\jotd>c:\Python27\Scripts\pip install C:\Users\jotd\Downloads\ansible-2.5.0a1-py2-none-any.whl
Processing c:\users\jotd\downloads\ansible-2.5.0a1-py2-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from ansible==2.5.0a1)
Collecting cryptography (from ansible==2.5.0a1)
<a lot of package collecting...>
Installing collected packages: idna, pycparser, cffi, asn1crypto, ipaddress, cryptography, pynacl, bcrypt, pyasn1, paramiko, ansible
  Running setup.py install for pycparser ... done
  Running setup.py install for ipaddress ... done
Successfully installed ansible-2.5.0a1 asn1crypto-0.24.0 bcrypt-3.1.4 cffi-1.11.4 cryptography-2.1.4 idna-2.6 ipaddress-1.0.19 paramiko-2.4.0 pyasn1-0.4.2 pycparser-2.18 pynacl-1.2.1
```

ok, installed, but let's try to import it:

```
C:\Users\jotd>c:\python27\python
Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:24:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ansible
>>>
```

works! yay!

Comment: IF the only issue is path length, I still think increasing max_path may help

Comment: Thank you for providing the GitHub link. i will follow it.

Comment: Symlink loops, I guessed it!  The name "circles" was a hint.   +1

Comment: yes, you were right. Emulated symlinks probably. thanks

Comment: How would I get a wheel file for 2.6.0? Been stuck on this for a while now :|

Answer (score 5):

I got ansible installed without using pip, which seemed pretty straight forward to me.

Steps:

- download compressed .tgz archive from https://pypi.org/project/ansible/
- open 7-zip with right-click **run as administrator** and extract. <- admin is necessary because of symbolic links
- opened an admin console in the folder and ran:

  > > python setup.py install

now ansible is installed on Windows.

Comment: The unzip didn't work for me - even as administrator. I used 7-zip to first delete the `test/integration/targets/copy` directory inside the archive, then extracted and then ran `python setup.py install`. All installed now. Thanks.

Comment: didn't work with version 2.6.1 - got error: can't copy 'lib\ansible\module_utils\ansible_release.py': doesn't exist or not a regular file

Answer (score -1):

I also ran into problems installing ansible on windows.  Instead of trying to install ansible on a platform it isn't meant for I suggest enabling the windows ubuntu subsystem.

See https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-ubuntu-on-windows

Once you do that [install ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html) through apt-get or pip.

--

**Installing with PIP:**

Make sure you have python3-disutils first:

> sudo apt install python3-distutils

and then install pip as per https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Try running ansible - if it cant be found you need to add site-packages directory to your $PATH.

To avoid all this installation work I suggest using apt-get.

Comment: isn"t apt-get for linux?

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre yes. But if you install the Ubuntu subsystem then you can use apt-get inside the subsystem.